# A lot of problems after chown -r user:user /

Tags: permissions, chown

I've executed this command `chown -r user:user /`after which I can't perform any sudo command. Also I can't connect to any Network. I want return all back. But how?

Comment: Did you run this command as `sudo` or as the root user?  'Cause otherwise it wouldn't have done much.  If you *did* run it as `sudo` or as root, you're hosed, and attempting to "revert" this is going to be TONS of pain, you'd be better off reinstalling after mounting to a LiveUSB/installer image, and copying off any data you want to keep to a second flashdrive then reinstall the system clean.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are unable to use `sudo` You would have to boot from a liveusb installation and change all of the permissions back from there.

As mentioned in Thomas Wards comment above, it would most likely be easier to use the liveusb to backup your data and then just reinstall the system

Comment: ... which is a lesson in futility because you'd need to have the 'original' permissions schema which only a 'clean' install would have.

Answer (score 1):

If you ran this as non-superuser (without `sudo` and just your own user), you probably didn't do *too* much damage because outside your own user directory and maybe some bits of `/tmp/` (which you can probably fix with a reboot), your user wouldn't have the permissions to chagne things much.

---

**However**, if you ran this as `sudo` or as the `root` user, you're literally hosed.

Attempting to revert *that* amount of damage is a lesson in futility and self-punishment, as you'd have to have an exemplar *clean* system to know how to reset the ownership and permissions to.  You'd also have to go directory by directory and file-by-file which is a VERY lengthy and nontrivial process that you'd have to do via the Live environment anyways.

Generally speaking, because you'd need to set up a system *just* to find the proper default permissions again, you'd be better off booting up to a LiveUSB / installer image, copying any data you want to keep off the drive as superuser in the Live environment to a second, external disk, and then blasting away the installed Ubuntu and reinstalling.